# function for a pointer to structure and copy it content without memcpy

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, structure

I'm trying to make a function that points to a single inventory structure(one record) and copies its content to an element in the gobal array defined in inventory.c. I would like to copy them member by member and return  an integer -1 if the copies fails. In my main fuctionm, I would like to iterate through my sample data and call the invSetRecord function for each element in the sampleData Array. I'm lost on what to do and need some help on this. I updated my inventory.c file. Im confused on my function. I was compiling it by itself. I dont understand how to get the productName to copy. Any suggestions? Also I'm having a hard time set up the counter for the inventory records.

Here's my instructions from my teacher,

Use the petstore files created for Lab 9 (Part 2) to complete this assignment.

Copy the following sample data into the `petstore_main.c` file:

```
# define SAMPLE_SZ 5

struct inventory_s sampleData[SAMPLE_SZ] = {
    { 1000, 1.49, 3.79, 10, 0, "Fish Food" },
    { 2000, 0.29, 1.59, 100, 1, "Angelfish" },
    { 2001, 0.09, 0.79, 200, 1, "Guppy" },
    { 5000, 2.40, 5.95, 10, 0, "Dog Collar, Large" },
    { 6000, 49.99, 129.99, 3, 1, "Dalmation Puppy" }
};
```

Define a function in the `inventory.c` file which has the following prototype (put the prototype in the `inventory.h` file)

```
int invSetRecord(struct inventory_s *ipx);
```

This function will take a pointer to a single inventory structure (a record) and copy its contents to an element in the global array defined in `inventory.c`. The target location (global array element) will be determined by the current size of the array, if the array is empty then the record is copied into element 0, if the current size is 1 it will be copied into element 1, etc. This means you need to define a global counter in `inventory.c` which tracks the number of elements in the array. In the invSetRecord function you will need to copy the structure member by member using a method appropriate to the type, e.g. simple assignment for the primitive data types, and strcpy() for the string data type. The function returns an integer value: if the copy operation fails (e.g. the global inventory array is full), the function returns -1, otherwise it returns 0.

In your main function in `petstore_main.c`, you will need to create a loop which iterates through the sample data and calls invSetRecord for each element in the sampleData array. For each call to invSetRecord you need to check the return value of the function and print an error if the operation failed or succeeded, and the corresponding record number. For instance, if the operation succeeds for all 5 sample data records, this is the output printed from your main function:

```
record #1 set successfully
record #2 set successfully
record #3 set successfully
record #4 set successfully
record #5 set successfully
```

If a call to invSetRecord fails (the function returns -1), the following message is printed:

```
error: could not set record 1
```

If an error occurs, you must break out of the loop at that point.

here's what i got so far I need some help. I been pulling my hair out all week trying to figure this one out. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
//inventory.c    
#include <stdio.h>

#include "inventory.h"
int i;
#define invSetRecord main

struct inventory_s inventory[MAX_INVENTORY];
int i;

int invSetRecord(struct inventory_s *ipx)
{

    int result;
    i = sizeof(MAX_INVENTORY)/sizeof(inventory[0]);

    if (i > MAX_INVENTORY)
    {
    result = -1;
    printf("%i", i);
    }
    if (i < MAX_INVENTORY)
    {
        result = 0;
        printf("%i", i);
        inventory[i].productNumber = ipx->productNumber;
        inventory[i].mfrPrice = ipx->mfrPrice;
        inventory[i].retailPrice = ipx->retailPrice;
        inventory[i].numInStock = ipx->numInStock;
        inventory[i].liveInv = ipx->liveInv;
        //inventory[i].productName= (ipx->productName);


        i++;
    }
    return result;



}
```

heres my inventory.h file...

```
#ifndef _INVENTORY_H_ //ensures that inventory.h does not run more than once
#define _INVENTORY_H_

#define  PRODUCTNAME_SZ 20
#define MAX_INVENTORY 50


struct inventory_s
{
    int productNumber;
    float mfrPrice;
    float retailPrice;
    int numInStock;
    char liveInv;
    char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ];
};

int invSetRecord(struct inventory_s *ipx);

#endif //_INVENTORY_H_
```

heres my main() file...

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "inventory.h"

#define SAMPLE_SZ 5

extern struct inventory_s inventory[MAX_INVENTORY]; 

struct inventory_s sampleData[SAMPLE_SZ]={

    { 1000, 1.49, 3.79, 10, 0, "Fish Food" },
    { 2000, 0.29, 1.59, 100, 1, "Angelfish" },
    { 2001, 0.09, 0.79, 200, 1, "Guppy" },
    { 5000, 2.40, 5.95, 10, 0, "Dog Collar, Large" },
    { 6000, 49.99, 129.99, 3, 1, "Dalmation Puppy"}
};

int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < SAMPLE_SZ; i++);
    invSetRecord(sampleData);

    printf("The product number is %i for sampleData element[]", sampleData[0].productNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The undefined reference to winmain is caused when the linker cant find the main function's defintion. Are you compiling just inventory.c on its own? You'll need to compile both `main.c` and `inventory.c` together so that the linker can find the definition of `int main()` (in `main.c`) AND the definitions for the functions declared in inventory.h (in `inventory.c`)

Comment: I was compiling it by itself then added #define invSetRecord main to the top and it runs fine now. I'm still confused on copying the productName to the pointer. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated some of the inventory.c file. I'm having a problem with the structure assignments. Does my format look correct? I'm trying to have the pointers of the structure copy what its pointing to in the function, so I can call it in my main function for each sampleData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the simple issues where your compiler is throwing errors and warnings:

```
#include "inventory.h"
int i;
#define invSetRecord main

struct inventory_s inventory[MAX_INVENTORY];
int i;
```

How many times do you need to declare `i`? There is no reason for `#define invSetRecord main`. As a note, when declaring a global, a more distinctive name than the very common `i` is advisable.

In `invSetRecord`, (using `idx` (index) for your `i`), why not simply do:

```
/* inventory.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "inventory.h"

int idx;

struct inventory_s inventory[MAX_INVENTORY];

int invSetRecord (struct inventory_s *ipx)
{
    if (idx == MAX_INVENTORY) return -1;

    inventory[idx].productNumber = ipx->productNumber;
    inventory[idx].mfrPrice      = ipx->mfrPrice;
    inventory[idx].retailPrice   = ipx->retailPrice;
    inventory[idx].numInStock    = ipx->numInStock;
    inventory[idx].liveInv       = ipx->liveInv;
    strcpy (inventory[idx].productName, ipx->productName);
    idx++;

    return 0;
}
```

Note, your compiler will be telling you you *cannot* simply assign `ipx->productName` to `inventory[idx].productName` since it is a character array (well `char *` after conversion). You must use `strcpy` (or `strncpy`) or simply iterate over `(ipx->productName)[]` until the *nul-terminating* character is reached copying char-by-char to `inventory[idx].productName[]`.

The following makes no sense at all:

```
    i = sizeof(MAX_INVENTORY)/sizeof(inventory[0]);
```

(you can only get the number of elements in an array (*not pointer*) *in the scope where the array is declared* by using `sizeof array/sizeof array[0]`. What you have above has no resemblance to the proper use.)

The remainder of your `inventory.h` seems fine. However the first line does NOT `//ensures that inventory.h does not run more than once` it insures that the header file `inventory.h` is not *included* more than once.

Your `main()` is -- creative... to say the least. What you are trying to accomplish is passing the *address of* `sampleData[i]` (e.g. `&sampleData[i]`) to `invSetRecord` (e.g. a pointer to the struct, not the struct itself).

Further, what happens with this code?

```
    for(i = 0; i < SAMPLE_SZ; i++);
```

**answer**: nothing. `i` simply changes value from `0 - SAMPLE_SZ` without effecting any other code. Why? The `;` following the loop is the same as:

```
    for(i = 0; i < SAMPLE_SZ; i++) {}
```

e.g. -- an empty block. Remove the `;` for the loop to operate on the following line.

It is unclear what you are trying to print at the end. Presuming you want the `productNumber` for every element, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "inventory.h"

#define SAMPLE_SZ 5

extern struct inventory_s inventory[MAX_INVENTORY]; 

struct inventory_s sampleData[] = {
    { 1000, 1.49, 3.79, 10, 0, "Fish Food" },
    { 2000, 0.29, 1.59, 100, 1, "Angelfish" },
    { 2001, 0.09, 0.79, 200, 1, "Guppy" },
    { 5000, 2.40, 5.95, 10, 0, "Dog Collar, Large" },
    { 6000, 49.99, 129.99, 3, 1, "Dalmation Puppy" }
};

int main (void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SAMPLE_SZ; i++)
        if (invSetRecord (&sampleData[i]) == 0)
            printf ("record #%d set successfully.\n", i);
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: could not set record %d.\n", i);
            break;
        }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up output formatting */

    for (i = 0; i < SAMPLE_SZ; i++)
        printf ("sampleData[%2d] : %d\n", i, sampleData[i].productNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Putting it altogether, compiling and running the code will produce the following:

```
$ ./bin/main
record #0 set successfully.
record #1 set successfully.
record #2 set successfully.
record #3 set successfully.
record #4 set successfully.

sampleData[ 0] : 1000
sampleData[ 1] : 2000
sampleData[ 2] : 2001
sampleData[ 3] : 5000
sampleData[ 4] : 6000
```

Look it all over and let me know if you have any questions. Just slow down and think through each line of the code. Also, if you are having difficulty with the code split between three different source files, you may want to simply use a single source file for initial development, then separate into the individual files when it all makes sense. That way, you eliminate all but just the code issues initially.

---

**Notes about using the IDE**

For sake of completeness, your `inventory.h` could be left pretty much as you have it. I made few changes (other than personal preference, e.g. `#define _INVENTORY_H_ 1` to actually define a value for `_INVENTORY_H_` rather than letting it default). I used the following:

```
#ifndef _INVENTORY_H_
#define _INVENTORY_H_ 1

#define PRODUCTNAME_SZ 20
#define MAX_INVENTORY 50

struct inventory_s {
    int productNumber;
    float mfrPrice;
    float retailPrice;
    int numInStock;
    char liveInv;
    char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ];
};

int invSetRecord (struct inventory_s *ipx);

#endif
```

As noted in the comments, I simply compiled and built the project with a single call to `gcc` from the command line. Specifically I used:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast inventory.c -o main main.c
```

The basic, minimum compile string required is:

```
$ gcc inventory.c -o main main.c
```

Which just says compile `main.c`, `-o main` outputting the resulting executable in a file named `main` (it can be whatever you want, `bananas` for that matter) and finally `inventory.c` which is what tells the compiler that in addition to `main.c` it must compile and link the code in `inventory.c` in order to produce a working executable. You run the code from the command line with:

```
$ ./main     (or ./bananas if you went that route)
```

The remaining options just enable *all compiler warnings* (so you can fix them before considering your code reliable), `-Ofast` enable all compiler optimizations (not that critical here), and sets the language standard to C11 with gnu extensions. I'll explain a bit further below.

`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` simply enable all *compiler warnings*. (use at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` with every project and *fix* all warnings before you consider your code reliable) For *Codeblocks* look in `Project->Build options...->Compiler Flags` (then check the box for `Enable all common compiler warnings ... [-Wall]`, and the next box for `-Wextra`) You can also check the `-pedantic` option, but that adds another layer of subtle warnings that get a bit down in the weeds for initial learning.

The `-std=gnu11` just tells the compiler to build with `C11` (and the `gnu extensions`). You can omit this flag and build to `C89` by default. (which is fine)

The `-Ofast` just enables all compiler optimizations. The `-Ofast` optimization is available for `gcc 4.6` and above, otherwise they are just `-O0` (that's `Oh zero`) meaning no optimization. The `-O1` or `-O2` and `-O3` levels just allow the compiler to make increasingly aggressive optimization to speed the code up -- like eliminating dead code, optimizing loops, etc)

For your `Debug` builds, you will generally not enable `-Ofast` optimization, but on Linux, include `-g` instead to generate debugging symbols for use with the `gdb` debugger. (I think Codeblocks does this for you automatically)

If you want to piecemeal compile to `inventory.c` to an object file first and then link the object file with `main.c` to make the `invSetRecord` function available to `main`, you could do:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c -o inventory.obj inventory.c
```

Which does just that, compile `inventory.c` to the object file `inventory.obj`. Finally, you would just compile `main.c` linking `inventory.obj` to create the final executable:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main inventory.obj main.c
```

(the order of the options isn't that important, just remember you must include any needed *libraries* before the source files that rely on code from the library.)

That should allow you to compile and link your code (either from the command line or in codeblocks). If you get stuck again, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rankin! I review everything you said, and I'm starting to understand it a little better. I'm having trouble with compiling it now. My build messages say ' undefined reference to invSetRecord' ,but I have it prototyped in my inventory.h file and have that file included at the top of the main here. Do you see anything wrong how I have them linked together? I'm using CodeBlocks to compile it, by the way.

Comment: You must compile both `inventory.c` and `main.c`. I do it all in one shot from the command line. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast inventory.c -o main main.c`. I hate IDE's (especially for people learning C) because they hide what are the very simple (but important) concepts of building code. Your error is due to `main.c` being compiled and not being able to find the function `invSetRecord` (which is in the `inventory.c` file). So you either compile `inventory.c` to *object* (e.g. `gcc -c inventory.c -o inventory.obj`), then `gcc main.c inventory.obj -o main`

Comment: (sorry ran out of room above -- do not forget `-Wall -Wextra` on every compile -- that enables almost all warnings, add `-pedantic` if you truly want to see all warnings). You can tell Codeblocks to compile both (or compile `inventory.c` to *object file* first, then include that as part of the compile of `main.c`. Give it a go and let me know if you run into more problems -- the key is to really (I mean *really*) understand what each line of code is doing. If you don't, then ask. C takes a while to learn -- but every minute spent is well worth the effort. (note, drop the `-std=gnu11` if needed

Comment: To see what you were facing, I went and installed codeblocks. Wow! That's a lot to take in. Don't get me wrong, it is good IDE, but for simple code (what you will see for the next year of your learning), it just adds another layer of learning. I suspect you have created your `'project'` (and all files are located in your project directory) If files are in separate directories, you must set the appropriate `Project->Build Options..` to set the search path and linker paths. Codeblocks will automatically build the required files in order if they are in a single directory.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I didn't have it setup right as a project in codeblocks. My teacher wants us to use multiple files in a project. I was trying to compile them without having them inside and linked together in a project folder.\